# Overlay Bar Plots with Line Plot in matlab with 2 y-axis by Creating 2nd axis

Tags: matlab, plot

I know there is a lot of similar questions on Stack-Overflow but I didn't find the one that I am specifically interested so I am going to ask again.

I am creating a graph where a line plot overlays with a stacked bar plot. I am NOT using plotyy. I am following the instruction provided here by creating a second axis system: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html

Basically, I plot my first data set, get the location of current axis, create a second axis at the same location, move y-axis to the right, x-axis to the top, and plot my second/third data set based on the new axis.

My data set is basically:

```
x
y1 (axis 1),y2,y3 (axis 2)
```

While I was able to plot y1,y2,y3 at two axis using all line style, I cannot get it to work with y2 and y3 being bar style. The second axis is somehow stuck with the first axis, instead moving to top-right. Also the first data set line just disappears.

[image: correct line plot]

[image: messed up line+bar plot]

Another small question I also have is how to remove the x-axis for the second axis (since they are essentially the same). I searched online and they said to set xtick to []. But I am getting error: Invalid or deleted object with command

```
set(ax1,'YTick',[])
```

Thank you very much.

As pointed out I don't have code uploaded, here you go ;)

```
% this script predicts 

% user prompt
prompt = {'Stock Name:','Cost per share($):','Current Value ($):','Holdings (shares):','Est. High ($)','Tolerance ($):'};
user_input = inputdlg(prompt);

% process user input
if isempty(user_input)
    stockname = 'APPLE.INC';
    x0 = 125.82;
    xn = 129.91;
    N0 = 80;
    xt = 135;
    tol = 20;
else
    [stockname,x0,xn,N0,xt,tol] = user_input{:};
    x0 = str2num(x0);
    xn = str2num(xn);
    xt = str2num(xt);
    N0 = str2num(N0);
    tol = str2num(tol);
end

% calculate sale-rebuy threshold 
xt = linspace(x0-tol,xt+tol,10);
[x0,xn,y,N0,Ny] = sale_rebuy(x0,xn,xt,N0);
profit_rebuy = Ny.*(xt-y);
profit_nosale = N0*(xt-x0);

% plotting
figure
line(xt,y,'Color','r','LineStyle','--');

ax1=gca;
set(ax1,'XColor','r');
set(ax1,'YColor','r');
ax1_pos = get(ax1,'Position');
ax2 = axes('Position',ax1_pos,...
    'XAxisLocation','top',...
    'YAxisLocation','right',...
    'Color','none');

profit = [profit_rebuy;profit_nosale]';
%bar(ax2,xt,profit,'stacked');
line(xt,profit_rebuy,'Parent',ax2,'Color','k','LineStyle',':');

title(stockname);
xlabel(ax1,'final price');
xlabel(ax2,'final price');
ylabel(ax1,'rebuy price');
ylabel(ax2,'profit');


% This is the function
function [x0,xn,y,N0,Ny] = sale_rebuy(x0,xn,xt,N0)
  y = (xn.*xt)./(xt-x0+xn);
  Ny = xn.*N0./y;

  x0 = x0;
  xn = xn;
  N0 = N0;
end
```

Comment: Its hard to tell what is wrong in your code because there is no code.

Comment: @AnderBiguri The code is uploaded, thanks for pointing out.